# jquery REGEX for longstring with azAZ-09-specialchars and |

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hello can someone help me in jquery regex?
whew coz im stack here since last night and finally iv'e decided to ask some help :)

any here's my regex abd the string is in exg variable.. then i want to split the string each

matches[0] = 'eNortjI0sLBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdH59RKc4M8&+SSXFzzXFz3UE9H9yzfYMfCYtPiDLes0NSAXCL3nIj0osJcIvNCjwxLv6z8YhPTXFxv8&KSMNekjIrgqqzQvOJyy0zXNPMoZ4vS0PQS4+S0&IIgU7OssPIolygXJWtcMMMFXCch|eNortjI0sLRScgQDz3yTfK98XCfHXDBDjzx3X4&cXCLXygKn4tzsNCNcJ+NMk+xEM6Ok&OIq1+DcXFxLw8AwjyhHb480lyxTg&LkKv8sXw&zpCSnJE+XYo&EVH&3yKyAsMjEtKxSi4CIqlwigwL&giinXDC3wCiXKBcla1wwpPEmEA==|';

matches[1] = 'eNortjI0NLJScgQDz3yTfK98XCdH9yCPZJ&CiCpD36xcMMuSsLwox6qAwMqkUAPTlChHI8ugvDQL9zzjbBMfT8u8RIOgMgvnHJ9SpzynvFDfQAugijBLv6CgXDBT&0LzKMdI06BIf9OyKGd&U58kN19fV8colygXJWtcMNaqJP8=|';

`var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[/-=&_]+|/g;`

`var exg = 'eNortjI0sLBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdH59RKc4M8&+SSXFzzXFz3UE9H9yzfYMfCYtPiDLes0NSAXCL3nIj0osJcIvNCjwxLv6z8YhPTXFxv8&KSMNekjIrgqqzQvOJyy0zXNPMoZ4vS0PQS4+S0&IIgU7OssPIolygXJWtcMMMFXCch|eNortjI0sLRScgQDz3yTfK98XCfHXDBDjzx3X4&cXCLXygKn4tzsNCNcJ+NMk+xEM6Ok&OIq1+DcXFxLw8AwjyhHb480lyxTg&LkKv8sXw&zpCSnJE+XYo&EVH&3yKyAsMjEtKxSi4CIqlwigwL&giinXDC3wCiXKBcla1wwpPEmEA==|eNortjI0NLJScgQDz3yTfK98XCdH9yCPZJ&CiCpD36xcMMuSsLwox6qAwMqkUAPTlChHI8ugvDQL9zzjbBMfT8u8RIOgMgvnHJ9SpzynvFDfQAugijBLv6CgXDBT&0LzKMdI06BIf9OyKGd&U58kN19fV8colygXJWtcMNaqJP8=|eNodwdEKgjAUXDDQf&ELnLk57GnXJaiQq4do923YSuXqQKNgXx90zl4yxspE&TUhD21cMNVmqzQkKbdYGVQ6rfzrIy9+nEThYPBvhLU2bpezFs&YSw4H2xdEj+t4mzoVz8Rhuy&i1KTL4BCIx5mcd1tt7Bc16uT4A7goJkI=|eNodyN0KwiAUXDDgd9kb2CzGujoqyeaJFjmKc9fYMCGxkLWfpy&6Lr9UMsbLDP6qyGMdBZzOFRsmq3RYXYN8tW8kUQRdyJ7k4SNq2fntbJwP7QWQ5HOcSeQEKcd0TGzB3XXhY2&wV&6h7a27b17KGQImm9ZOpEhl+y9eOlwnaQ==|eNortjI0NLBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHv3J3b9P80rwo54pwTy+DgkR3M3eXTMdAY6ekjChHD4PcFJ+KNIMg54Bko9IKxxC&XFyTQl+niqLc7NAkV6PIXCKjgFCD0FQTc4vSCuf0JP+SJIPcspKsKEdj48ys9CiXKBcla1wwr5gmBA==|eNortjI0sLBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHp1KniMLwiNKglFxc71L3wqrAPEe3UF&PHMuq9BDPXDCflKTkkJDQCIM0s&B8rwxLR5co5ySXbJ9SY7dSH&+SyAqL7JQkV3cPX&NKc9OilKoU51ST&CQ&k6Ki0vIolygXJWtcMKhcMCZa|eNortjI0MLJScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHP5MoxySjJMfIFL&CEsuSUKNQv4LiSre8KKco56IUT3&L0CyfgMIox&IoXCevKFwns&R011THgMKsfLcoZ++MQo&0cNeyIPOqkPTIqrCqCstcMM+C8ChHz8goFyVrXDCmkyQg|eNortjI0NLJScgQDz3yTfK98XCdH&4z8yCin0szUgNwo54zkkBDTJB&TrIBA06S8XFxvr7SKyuDsKOeIZOPcsFA&&4woZ49UU&ekIKMq&7DURCOLimRjX9eKSmdDxxwXZ4&wjDT&lLDsJI&iqpB01yhcJ4v0KJcoFyVrXDA8ZVwnTQ==|eNortjI0MrBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHLy&LSLfMyOxcIvfIioJit9Lc9NC04NK8NEvncHe&9Byv5MRwy8pC79ywgLT0SJ+qjORCC5PK0oh8i8yU0gpPR9PK7BJXn9SCxDznsEQXb7e8LLMCp+L8tMTyKJcoF7XUioLMotTi+Mw8WwMla1ww8SosXw==|eNortjI0NLRScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHr0pcJ+PAdP9sc+NcIvcyY4PEoNywyuyKzOQsC8twDx9Hg7TUkHyv7BDjMtPg3LwcjyinqlwiNxcXXCeXKFwn7wggEWmck59YHJhZ5Z4ZmF4R5eSfaFnkWuzpVFRglpxcXB7lEuWiZA1cMO+XJv4=|eNortjI0MLdScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHr7LgEpekEmO&xIBgo5CMoOSSKu&QDKPK5OziojS&&Bwvk&BK4yqLCFOjTNNcXC9Tz8C0jLzSkuCMYI88v8KIwORQi&TMQLM8i&B8Sy9Pl7QqXwt&gxQvrzLHKJcoFyVrXDCNviXB|eNortjI0NLRScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHn4pCp5yQxNIkM8MQ97SI0PLkoIqy9DJvZ3PXgPDwgKSIKKfwPKfi&CqvtAqTTNf0YMdwS8cM&yjH7Mr0omTTsLQqg&RcXLOK9Oz00LDgwijHCOeqyuC8KFwnf2fvSMcolygXJWtcMD&GXCfp|eNortjI0NLBScgQDz3yTfK98XCdHF6&gcEdTr5SiNO8KY1wnk1KLIE&&yowox+JcMB&XlGyzQH8&gwKvyIjyEMuyNI+ktMSQ7DDzdAsTA&fyKMckl&KS9HDDgNRKL0+jkCintLCStFwin+LcRC+PXFxcJ7+qwCiXKBcla1wwqjUmMg=='`

```
   if(regex.test(exg)) {
      var matches = exg.match(regex);
      for(var match in matches) {
            alert(matches[match]);
      } 
       } else {
         alert("No matches found!");
       }`
```

but my regex won't work whew can someone give me a right regex for it? :) please help..

Comment: So what are you trying to match exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erm... how about just using `split` like so `marches = yourString.split('|');`

this will return an array of strings, but the pipe char's will not be included, but just concat them to the substring if you need them.

Comment: yes iv'e tried by seems so slow, coz im retrieving more that 14000+ strings so that's why im using regex coz regex is faster thab spliting ;)

Comment: you could use `=|` or `==|` or any other delimiter of you want. In your example string, not all substrings end with `==|`, some are only delimited by `=|`, so I would only use the pipe, you can deal with trailing delim's however you like. Alternatively, you could use a regex the likes of `yourString.split(/\=+\|/g)`

Comment: @HannibalBurr: since when is regex faster then splitting on a pattern delimiter faster then on a **literal** delimiter. You'r effectively splitting your string using regex, so it amounts to the same, really... but hey, if you want a regex: `matches = yourString.match(/[^\|=]+\=+\|/g)`; matches everythin except one ore more `=` followed by pipe

Comment: glad to be of assistance. BTW: if speed is your main concern, why not ditch jQuery? :-P... sorry, couldn't resist

Answer (score 1):

Elias answer is probably the easiest way to do this but if you insist on regex then how about this:

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\/-=&_+]+\|{0,1}/g
```

Explanation of your regex and why it doesn't work:

```
[a-zA-Z]+  // Match one or more a-z upper or lower case
[0-9]+     // *THEN* match one or more 0-9
[/-=&_]+   // *THEN* match one or more of these characters
|          // *THEN* match a pipe
```

The problem here is that the letters, numbers and symbols in your search string are mixed together. Therefore they all need to go inside square brackets together so you match one or more of all of them together in *any* order. Yours puts them in a specific order, letters first, then numbers, then symbols.

The `{0,1}` on the end matches either zero or one pipe and will therefore catch the last match which does not have a pipe at the end.

Incidentely there's no such thing as JQuery regex. The regex functions are javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a slash before |, so this may be what you want?

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\/-=&_]+\|/g;
```